# How to fix glitch with gif animation when loading through Konva.js and Gifler?

Tags: javascript, html, animated-gif, konvajs

I did the gif-animation loading, following the example in the documentation. However, frames are skipped and frames are displayed incorrectly.

This happens to many gif files. Please, how to fix it, does anyone know?

Here is an example error:

```js
 var width = window.innerWidth;
      var height = window.innerHeight;

      var stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: width,
        height: height
      });

      var layer = new Konva.Layer();
      stage.add(layer);

      var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      // use external library to parse and draw gif animation
      function onDrawFrame(ctx, frame) {
        // update canvas size
        canvas.width = frame.width;
        canvas.height = frame.height;
        // update canvas that we are using for Konva.Image
        ctx.drawImage(frame.buffer, 0, 0);
        // redraw the layer
        layer.draw();
      }

      gifler('https://i.gifer.com/8RDg.gif').frames(canvas, onDrawFrame);

      // draw resulted canvas into the stage as Konva.Image
      var image = new Konva.Image({
        image: canvas
      });
      layer.add(image);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@4.0.4/konva.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/gifler@0.1.0/gifler.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to try to use another library. I used [libgif.js](https://github.com/buzzfeed/libgif-js/tree/0654e7f2dbce9b8787ca0eb4c42c558ae0601bc) to solve this issue that is an example

```
  var width = window.innerWidth;
  var height = window.innerHeight;

  var templateImage = new Image();

  templateImage.onload = function(){
    // image  has been loaded
    drawKonva(templateImage);
  };

  templateImage.src = "https://i.gifer.com/8RDg.gif";
```

function drawKonva(templateImage) {

```
  var stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: width,
    height: height,
  });

  var layer = new Konva.Layer();
  stage.add(layer);

  var gif = new SuperGif({
    gif: templateImage,
    progressbar_height: 0,
    auto_play: true,
    loop_mode: true,
    draw_while_loading: true
  });

  gif.load();

  var gif_canvas = gif.get_canvas(); // the lib canvas
  // a copy of this canvas which will be appended to the doc
  var canvas = gif_canvas.cloneNode();
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  function anim(t) { // our animation loop
      context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); // in case of transparency ?
      context.drawImage(gif_canvas, 0, 0); // draw the gif frame
      layer.draw();
      requestAnimationFrame(anim);

  };

  anim();

  // draw resulted canvas into the stage as Konva.Image
  var image = new Konva.Image({
    image: canvas,
    draggable: true
  });
  layer.add(image);
```

}